# The sort function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following Array of results in contactArray variable. Here What I need is I'll need to sort the following records by LastModifiedDate of a particular record.

In the front end I have 3 records and First time I select only one record and do some manipulation in the back end and show again to the front end by Asc order.

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {Id: "0034E00000nNLPfQAO", Name: "Test Contact 1"}
    1: {Id: "0034E00000nNLTbQAO", Name: "Test Contact 2", LastModifiedDate: "2019-03-28T09:53:00.000Z", Status__c: "Pending", Status_Reason__c: undefined}
    2: {Id: "0034E00000nP8VuQAK", Name: "Test Contact 3"}
```

using the below code snippet the sortedArray was like below,

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {Id: "0034E00000nNLTbQAO", Name: "Test Contact 2", LastModifiedDate: "2019-03-28T09:53:00.000Z", Status__c: "Pending", Status_Reason__c: undefined}
    1: {Id: "0034E00000nNLPfQAO", Name: "Test Contact 1"}
    2: {Id: "0034E00000nP8VuQAK", Name: "Test Contact 3"}
```

Second attempt I have select another unselect record from the front-end,

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {Id: "0034E00000nNLPfQAO", Name: "Test Contact 1", LastModifiedDate: "2019-03-28T09:59:13.000Z", Status__c: "Pending", Status_Reason__c: undefined}
    1: {Id: "0034E00000nNLTbQAO", Name: "Test Contact 2", LastModifiedDate: "2019-03-28T09:53:00.000Z", Status__c: "Pending", Status_Reason__c: undefined}
    2: {Id: "0034E00000nP8VuQAK", Name: "Test Contact 3"}
```

and the sorted array was like below,

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {Id: "0034E00000nNLPfQAO", Name: "Test Contact 1", LastModifiedDate: "2019-03-28T09:59:13.000Z", Status__c: "Pending", Status_Reason__c: undefined}
    1: {Id: "0034E00000nNLTbQAO", Name: "Test Contact 2", LastModifiedDate: "2019-03-28T09:53:00.000Z", Status__c: "Pending", Status_Reason__c: undefined}
    2: {Id: "0034E00000nP8VuQAK", Name: "Test Contact 3"}
```

The following is the code snippet I have used to sort the array,

```
var sortedContactArray = contactArray.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
var tc1RefUndefined = obj1.LastModifiedDate == null ? 1 : 0;
var tc2RefUndefined = obj2.LastModifiedDate == null ? 1 : 0;

if (tc1RefUndefined || tc2RefUndefined) {
    return new Date(tc1RefUndefined) - new Date(tc2RefUndefined);
    }
});
```

Did I missed anything?

Comment: you should do the opposite `if (!tc1RefUndefined && !tc2RefUndefined) { .. }` also provide some fallback when the lastModifiedDate of either object is indeed undefined

Comment: you are testing for `null` when you should be testing for `undefined`. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Your logic for Undefined is backwards, isn't it? You set a Truthy value if it is `null` and zero (falsy) if it isn't.

Comment: I agree with @ADyson accessing properties on an object returns undefined, not null

Comment: You don't return anything if both `obj1.LastModifiedDate` and `obj2.LastModifiedDate` are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move items without `LastModifiedDate` property (or any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value) to bottom and then sort the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date by string.

```js
var array = [{ Id: "0034E00000nNLPfQAO", Name: "Test Contact 1", LastModifiedDate: "2019-03-28T09:59:13.000Z", Status__c: "Pending", Status_Reason__c: undefined }, { Id: "0034E00000nNLTbQAO", Name: "Test Contact 2", LastModifiedDate: "2019-03-28T09:53:00.000Z", Status__c: "Pending", Status_Reason__c: undefined }, { Id: "0034E00000nP8VuQAK", Name: "Test Contact 3" }];

array.sort(({ LastModifiedDate: a }, { LastModifiedDate: b }) =>
     !a - !b || (a || '').localeCompare(b || ''));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: got 'Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined' error.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove ternary function in your sort conditiona and directly use LastModifiedDate for comparison.

```js
var x = [{Id: "0034E00000nNLPfQAO", Name: "Test Contact 1", LastModifiedDate: "2019-03-28T09:59:13.000Z", Status__c: "Pending", Status_Reason__c: undefined},{Id: "0034E00000nNLTbQAO", Name: "Test Contact 2", LastModifiedDate: "2019-03-28T09:53:00.000Z", Status__c: "Pending", Status_Reason__c: undefined},{Id: "0034E00000nP8VuQAK", Name: "Test Contact 3"}];

var y = x.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
var tc1RefUndefined = obj1.LastModifiedDate;   //<-- remove ternary
var tc2RefUndefined = obj2.LastModifiedDate;   //<-- remove ternary

if (tc1RefUndefined || tc2RefUndefined) {
    return new Date(tc1RefUndefined) - new Date(tc2RefUndefined);
    }
});

console.log(y)
```

Reason your code is not working is because when there is "LastModifiedDate" present in your object, you are assigning `1` to the local variable.

So when you run sort function for `contactArray[0] and contactArray[1]`

```
var tc1RefUndefined = 0;//(result of ternary condition)
var tc2RefUndefined = 0;//(result of ternary condition)

if (tc1RefUndefined || tc2RefUndefined) { //this will not run due to false
    return new Date(tc1RefUndefined) - new Date(tc2RefUndefined);
    }
})
//so your array remain unaffected
```

Comment: You are saying me to do something below,

array.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.LastModifiedDate) - new Date(a.LastModifiedDate);
});

If so I have tried this solution as well but no luck.

Comment: `array.sort(function(a,b){ if (a.LastModifiedDate || b.LastModifiedDate) { return new Date(b.LastModifiedDate) - new Date(a.LastModifiedDate); } });`  only returning if condition is true(means any of one object contains LastModifiedDate).

Comment: no luck. It's not working. The same issue occurred like in the question.

Comment: I don't know the reason why it is not working in your code(might be due to some other problem), but if you click on "Run code snippet" you will see the that here it is working

Comment: The code needs to be like this var sortedContactArray = contactArray.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
  return (new Date(obj1.LastModifiedDate || 0)) - 
         (new Date(obj2.LastModifiedDate || 0));
});